# Specify Groovy AntBuilder execution directory

Tags: maven, groovy, antbuilder

I can execute a pom.xml with goals using AntBuilder like so.

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.sequential {
    exec(executable:'mvn') {
        arg(value:'clean')
        arg(value:'install')
    }
}
```

But how do I specify the execution directory to the AntBuilder? I'd like to just pass an absolute path.

For the record I've tried.

```
ant.project.setProperty('basedir', "${serviceRootDir}/")
```

and

```
ant.sequential {
    mkdir(dir:"${serviceRootDir}/")...
```

You'd think this would be clear in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ant.exec(executable:"ls", dir:"/your/desired/directory")
```

It executes `ls` in the given directory, so `mvn` should work.